# Value not saving in textbox when changed by javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, postback

I have a javascript function as follows:

```
        Dim s As New StringBuilder
    s.Append("<script type=""text/javaScript"">")

    s.Append("var result = new Object();" & ControlChars.CrLf)
    s.Append("if (window.returnValue == 'undefined') { window.returnValue = ''; }" & ControlChars.CrLf)
    s.Append("function ReturnClaimCode(id) { " & ControlChars.CrLf)
    s.Append("document.getElementById('" & txtClaimSelected.UniqueID & "').value=id;" & ControlChars.CrLf)
    s.Append("document.getElementById('" & btnAllocate.UniqueID & "').disabled = false;" & ControlChars.CrLf)
    s.Append("}" & ControlChars.CrLf)
    s.Append("</script>")

    If Not ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("ReturnClaimCodeJs") Then
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "ReturnClaimCodeJs", s.ToString())
    End If
```

This, when executed, sets the value of the textbox 'txtClaimSelected' to the ID which can be '1', '2', '3' etc. This works correctly. My problem is that when I go to click a button on the form (after the ID value has been put into the textbox by this javascript), the value obtained by

```
Dim valueoftextbox = txtClaimSelected.Text
```

is not the value that I see in the textbox. It is the default value before the javascript is run (which is the word "None"). How can I 'store' this value or make my code see the updated contents of the text box?

I have tried forcing a postback in the javascript through

```
 s.Append("__doPostBack('','');" & ControlChars.CrLf)
```

and this does cause a postback, but the value is always lost again.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Looks like a ViewState issue. The Web Form create a hidden field for every input to hold the view state. Maybe you are getting the value from the hidden input instead of the text box. Try to add EnableViewState="false" on your text box and test it again!

Answer (score 1):

My apologies. The referenced textbox was set to readonly. When I changed this setting, the new value was stored okay.